# How to remove SQL Server completely?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, sql-server

I have faulty installatinon of SQL Server and want to remove it completely. The problem is there are too many entries in Apps & features in control panel (Uninstall programs).

I followed [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M1W6.png) Microsoft documentation to uninstall and the key really is to selected the right item `Microsoft SQL Server (version) (Bit)` and that brings up the right uninstall dialog to uninstall it. But it still leaves several items that has `SQL Server` in the name. My question is, should I individually remove them as well for full removal? This includes Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio too.

Btw I had to stop `SQL Server (MSSQLServer)` service before uninstall otherwise it will failed at couple of components. If that happens, you just stop the service and re-run the uninstaller again to remove the remaining items.

[image]

I want to clean the system completely and delete the folder `C:\Program Files \Microsoft SQL Server` in part because this folder a whopping 345 GB with ton of .dmp file as you can see the last two folders seems to be some kind of duplicate.

[image]

So is good to uninstall all these entries with SQL Server in it? Or can I just delete 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` for this time to clean up?

I have Visual Studio 2019 on my system and I want a properly installed SQL Server with it which is what I would be installing again after full clean its bad bad installation.

Comment: None of those programs you listed is actually Microsoft SQL Server.  The process of uninstalling SQL Server doesn’t delete dmp files as they were not installed by the installation process

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm..all these components did come back when I installed SQL server fresh.

Comment: They are also installed by Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

Well I went ahead and uninstalled all these SQL Server entries listed in Apps & Features, rebooted PC and the deleted the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` folder which freed up 350 GB of disk space. Rebooted again and nothing seems to be broken and Visual Studio 2019 runs fine so I guess that's a full removal.

Also, when I uninstalled all those SQL Server components, there were still a lot of SQL Server services running and I was not sure if they will go away but after reboot, they all are gone so that's good. No just disabled, they don't exist anymore so that's good.

And again to emphasis, I did had to stop the main SQL Service (not others) in order to completely uninstall it, namely the following components remained when I hadn't stopped the service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this [solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/370289/uninstalling-sql-server2019.html) for those of you who are still unable to resolve this issue. It involves deleting SQL-related keys using Regedit.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1106125)